# Box Api v2.0 transition from v1.0 Objective C Understanding

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, curl

I am in the process of converting my Box v1.0 api calls to v2.0.  I am having problems understanding Box's examples using 'Curl' and converting to current v1.0 'URL' code. I probably just don't understand 'Curl' more than the info that Box posted on developers site.  Here is an Example:

current v1.0 api call to download a file.

```
NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.box.com/api/1.0/download/%@/%@",cfgBoxAuthToken,@"somefile"];
```

Box definition of how to do with v2.0 api call.

```
curl -L https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID/content -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

my attempt to convert to v2.0 api in objective c

```
NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/files/%@/%@",@"somefile",cfgBoxAuthToken];
```

what am i doing wrong?  i imagine that once i get this "Curl" example down i can convert my other Box calls.

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because their API is using OAuth2, they're requiring the Authorization header to be in your API call. `-H` in CURL passes header elements.

You need to now define the url independently from the header, using something like:

`NSString *authHeader =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", accessToken];`

More information on passing headers with API calls can be found here: [Basic authorization in NSMutableURLRequest isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311322/basic-authorization-in-nsmutableurlrequest-isnt-working)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  so i assume i am to use POST now for all communication with Box?  and i should add authHeader to forHTTPHeaderField?  thanks again!

Comment: You don't actually need to use `POST` to pass header information -- you can still `GET` but provide the header in the response stream. **More info** Many OAuth2 APIs allow you to pass the `access_token` url query parameter (which is an option) but ever you need to make a `POST`, you'd have to handle it the header way anyway. In short, it's always best to keep it consistent wherever possible, and passing it in the header will work for every type of RESTful API call.